# Is there a way to track memory leaks?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks

I'm asking myself whether there's a proper way to detect undestroyed instances of an object systematically. Learning that even using smart pointers like std::shared_ptr can result in memory leaks when estalishing circular references I became a bit paranoid abount this topic. When programs become bigger and bigger it becomes impossible to check for memory leaks just by looking at the code.

**Therefore I came up with an extremely naive approach within a few minutes to track stuff like that. I would like to ask for your opinion about that and things i might miss here:**

My idea is to define a template class which defines every constructor (default, copy, move) and increments on creation an static counter of created instances and decrements that counter on destruction.

Every class I want to track inherits from that class:

Watch this code:

```
template<typename T>
class creationTracker
{
public: 
    creationTracker() { ++createdInstances; }
    creationTracker(const creationTracker&) {++createdInstances; }
    creationTracker(creationTracker&&) noexcept { ++createdInstances; }

    virtual ~creationTracker() { --createdInstances; }

    static unsigned createdInstances;
};

template<typename T>
unsigned creationTracker<T>::createdInstances{ 0 };

/* example class to demo detection of circular references */
class foo : public creationTracker<foo>
{
public:
    void setSharedPointer(std::shared_ptr<foo> p) { pv = p; }
    
private:
    std::shared_ptr<foo> pv;
};
```

Every class inherited from that creationTracker has its one static counter.
The class foo is used to enforce a circular reference when used in a wrong way:
For example like this:

```
int main() 
{   
    {//inner scope to be able to print instances before exiting main

        std::shared_ptr<foo> foo1(new foo);
        std::shared_ptr<foo> foo2(new foo);
        foo1->setSharedPointer(foo2);
        foo2->setSharedPointer(foo1);

        std::cout << "In Scope: " << foo::createdInstances << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Scope exit: " << foo::createdInstances << std::endl;
}
```

Console output:
In Scope: 2
Scope exit: 2 // not destroyed as expected

On the otherhand doing this also detects correct destruction of every instance:

```
int main() 
{       
    {//inner scope to be able to print instances before exiting main
        foo foo1{};                     // normal construct
        foo foo2{ foo1 };               // copy
        foo foo3{ std::move(foo1) };    // move construct
        foo foo4 = foo2;                // copy assignment
        foo foo5 = std::move(foo3);     // move assignment
        
        std::cout << "In Scope: " << foo::createdInstances << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Scope exit: " << foo::createdInstances << std::endl;
}
```

Console output:
In Scope: 5
Scope exit: 0  all instances destroyed as expected

Consider that I didnt spend much time developing this approach so take that into account if I miss trivial things.

I would really appreciate your opinions whether this approach can lead to successful tracking of created and destroyed instances or whether this is an dead end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There’s tools like valgrind that do this for you, at least. Also note that shared pointers shouldn’t be used everywhere and especially in cases where a circular reference might happen. Usually there is a unique pointer, or raw pointers, and shared pointers only when really needed. But of course there may be cases where they’re needed and circular case is possible.

Comment: `creationTracker(creationTracker&&)` on move constructor you shouldn't increase the counter.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 has built-in heap snapshot and leak detection capabilities.